# python iterating over dictionaries sorted by values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Piece of code below. Can anyone explain why iterating over dictionary, last lines, that has been sorted by values still outputs dictionary not sorted by values? Same applies when I try saving the dictionary.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

x = {1: 2999, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0 }
srtkeys = sorted(x, key=x.get)
ds={}
print "\ncreating dict sorted by values"
for w in srtkeys:`enter code here`
        print w,x[w]
        ds[w] = x[w]

print "\nprinting dict sorted by values"
print ds

print "\niterating over dict sorted by values"
for k,v in ds.iteritems():
        print str(k)+":"+str(v)
```

Output:

```
creating dict sorted by values
0 0
2 1
4 3
3 4
1 2999

printing dict sorted by values
{0: 0, 1: 2999, 2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 3}

iterating over dict sorted by values
0:0
1:2999
2:1
3:4
4:3
```

Answer (score 1):

Dict is never ordered by definition. You may want to use [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 0):

A dict has no inherent order, so sorting doesn't make sense. If you want the key:value pairs in a certain order, just loop over the list of ordered keys, like in your first loop.